# find 4 records in database and check if exist in other table

Tags: php, mysqli

I am sitting here and twisting my head for a mysql query that need select 4 records with a catogory and needs check that 4 records in an other table for an userid to check if a message have been send to a customer already if it have been I need to run the query again :

```
$result=mysqli_query($conn, "Select * from messages where approved='1' AND 
catogory='".$catogory."' ORDER by rand() LIMIT 4");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))


        $result=mysqli_query($conn, "select * from send_messages where 
message_id='".$id."' AND username='".$username."'");
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($rowcount > "0"){
            header("location: index.php?username=$username");
            exit();
        }
echo "<input type='radio' id='test' name='message' value='$row[id]'><label for='test'>$row[message]</label><br>";
    echo "</form>";
```

The code works good for 1 record but I need to print the 4 records out and then I try this code it shows nothing

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the first mysql result variable `$result` with your second `mysqli_query()` call. This means that your while loop in line 3 will actually check the content of the mysql query in line 6. At the end of your loop this result set will be empty, even when there might be more messages available.

Use different result variables for the different mysql queries, so you work on either the result set of "SELECT * FROM messages" or on the result set of "SELECT * FROM send_messages".

Comment: Hmm Could you come with a example how to do it, please?

Comment: name one variable `$result1`, the other one `$result2`.

Comment: Nope still not working, it need get the 4 id's in the first query so that it can run them in the second query and finally echo out 4 messages